# Using global variables as return storage for batch functions

Tags: batch-file

I'm using global variable to store return value of batch "function".
And it changes in strange way:

```
result local = 1
result global = 1
result = 4
```

So, somehow result is changing back to 4 after function call. What's wrong here?

```
set result=4

if %build%==1 (
    call :build_1
    echo "result=%result%"
    if %result%==4 (
        exit /b 4
        goto error
    )
    call :build_2
    if %result%==4 (
        exit /b 4
        goto error
    )
    call :build_3
    if %result%==4 (
        exit /b 4
        goto error
    )
    call :build_4
    if %result%==4 (
        exit /b 4
        goto error
    )
    goto success
)


rem return error/success code in result variable
:build_1
    setlocal

    rem Stage 1

    call    :build_one_unit
    if %errorlevel%==4 (
        echo FAILED!
        set result=4
        exit /b
    )

    rem Stage 2

    call    :build_one_unit
    if %errorlevel%==4 (
        echo FAILED!
        set result=4
        exit /b
    )

    set result=1
    echo "result local = %result%"
    endlocal & set result=%result%
    echo "result global = %result%"

goto:eof
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if %build%==1 ( ...... )`, yes, from open parenthesis to close parenthesis, is read and interpreted as a block. When this happens, result variable has a value of 4. When the block is interpreted, all variables are replaced with their values. Not when execution reaches the line with `if %result%==4`, but when the initial if was processed.

What you need is called delayed variable expansion. It allows you to use variables with !var! (instead of %var%) notation, saying to cmd that this variables need to be examined/replaced when accessed, not when the block was interpreted. Your code should be as :

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set return=4

if %build%==1 (
    call :build_1
    echo "result=!result!"
    if !result!==4 (
        exit /b 4
        goto error
    )
    ....
    ....
)
```